# MySQL mejor actualizar row entera o campos concretos

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

estoy recibiendo 3 veces al día unos ficheros csv de unos 250.000 registros con unos 20 campos.  Los proceso con Python y Pandas para formatear los campos previo a cargarlos en su tabla de MySQL.  El tema es que para no tener 10 minutos comparando registro a registro con lo que hay en la tabla, quiero cargar la tabla que ya está en la BBDD en un dataframe Pandas y compararlo con el dataframe Pandas del csv que llega y sólo insertar y actualizar los datos nuevos.

Una vez haya extraído los registros nuevos, ¿qué es más rápido para el motor de MySQL, hacer un update de todos los campos del registro o hacer un update del campo que se a actualizado de ese registro?

El problema es que no recibo solamente ese fichero, estoy recibiendo unos 20 que se reciben a la vez cada 8 horas.  Si todos se ponen a cargar a la vez y tardan entre 5-10 minutos cada uno se puede ralentizar las consultas al formulario web donde los operadores trabajan consultan y modifican estos datos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende y creo que falta contexto. ¿Preguntas si es más rápido actualizar la tabla entera o una actualización parcial, solo de aquellos que requieren ser actualizados? Es evidente que actualizar una tabla completa sería absurdo. 250,000 registros, 3 veces al día, no es nada, salvo que la BD esté en un servidor con recursos muy limitados. Lo más importante es escribir un código optimizado (transacciones, actualización por lotes) y que la BD tenga los índices correctos, que sea InnoDB, etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, aclaro lo que pueda.  Me refiero a que si después de comparar las dos tablas, la antigua con la nueva, el resultado es que hay que actualizar 500 registros de los 250.000, ¿qué opción consume más recursos de MySQL, hacer un update de cada uno de los registros o sólo actualizar el campo concreto que lo necesite de ese registro?  Es decir si un registro de la tabla tiene 20 campos y sólo es necesario actualizar una fecha, ¿qué consume más recursos hacer un update de todos los campos o sólo del campo de esa fecha?

Comment: Es evidente que consume menos recursos actualizar sólo ese campo. Por lo demás, puede que el manejador no actualice aquellas columnas cuyos valores sean iguales (eso lo puedes probar haciendo un UPDATE en el que seteas datos similares a los ya existentes en una fila, verás que las filas afectadas serán `0`). Por otra parte, si una columna es parte de un índice o de una llave, cuando actualizas esa columna el manejador tendrá trabajo para actualizar también el índice. Lo que me pregunto es por qué no actualizas directamente, o sea, por qué comparas primero por un lado para luego actualizar ¿?

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia ni programando ni en MySQL.  La máquina con MySQL es una máquina virtual con recursos limitados y que espera que todos los proyectos se dupliquen en peso de ficheros a cargar (este es uno de ellos y los demás tienen ficheros más pesados) .  Me han pedido que optimice la carga.  La idea es que Python con pandas compare las tablas, la que llega con la que está en memoria.

Comment: A continuación procesaría sólo los registros a insertar como nuevos o actualizar los existentes pero sólo el campo concreto, ya que el 50% de campos del registro son de datos que no cambian.  Por eso preguntaba si la consulta SQL de UPDATE saldría mejor en cuanto a consumo de recursos recorriendo actualizando todos los campos del registro, o que construya para cada registro una consulta SQL UPDATE con el campo o varios campos a actualizar, ya que pandas puede devolver los campos que han cambiado.

Comment: Como dije antes, es más costoso un UPDATE a todas las columnas que a una sola, no tiene ningún sentido, ni siquiera desde el punto de vista lógico. Por otro lado, optimizarías aún más si haces el UPDATE en la misma comparación (evitas leer la tabla dos veces así como almacenar aquellos datos que deben ser actualizados en otra parte, etc). Como también ya dije, podrías usar transacciones y hacer actualizaciones por lotes (por ejemplo, de 100 en 100 o de 200 en 200 o como quieras según las capacidades) y controlar posibles errores de algún modo.

Comment: Una consulta como esta, actualizaría al instante, sin necesidad de enrollarte guardando para luego actualizar: `UPDATE laTabla SET laColumna=elValor WHERE laColumna=elCriterio`  Ahí se actualizará `laColumna` con `elValor` cuando el `WHERE` se cumpla. Esa consulta se haría durante la lectura de tu archivo de 200,000 entradas. Dado que probablemente sea mucha carga, puedes ir leyendo el archivo por partes y actualizando, guardando un log o algo para cuando ocurran errores.

Comment: La comparación la hace python con la librería pandas en memoria con todo el dataframe y devuelve el resultado.  Digamos que no se puede ver lo que está haciendo en un registro concreto para que antes que pase al siguiente actualizar.  Me miro lo de las transacciones.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso no importa, desde Phyton o desde donde sea tú puedes acceder a la base de datos para verificar qué datos necesitan ser actualizados.